# Is it possible to invalidate a token with stateless logic (no database)?

Tags: database, web-applications, token, serverless, stateless

I need a serverless communication between a server(less backend) and a client. The client asks for a token. When the client makes a request with this token, the backend generates a new token and sends it back to the client. When the client tries to make a request with a previous token, the backend rejects it. I don't want the backend to keep track, either in ram or in a database, a whitelist or a blacklist of valid/invalid tokens.  The backend is allowed to have a static lookup table or/and a static rule/algorithm to perform this logic if needed (to use the information inside token's payload).
So, is it possible to achieve something like this ? Is there a way to apply certain kind of information inside each token to know wether you have accepted it once or not ?

Comment: .............No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your scenario the server is stateless (at least regarding authentication) so you cannot use the state of the server to discriminate if a received token is already used.
2. Also the moment you generate the token it is before it's first usage, so you cannot inject into it anything that tells if it was used or not: simply you don't have that information at that time of course.

So basically if your only information containers are these two (stateless server and self generated token) the answer is **no** no matter *how* it is done; simply there is no place where this bit of information (is this token last one or not) can be placed in the moment the information is generated (at the first usage time).

Theoretically speaking you can send this information to a third party entity and ask it back when you need it.. ..but this is just cheating: if you are not accepting a DB or RAM or filesystem storage, I suppose that *sending this information somewhere* through an API or else is just an excluded option as the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try TOTP, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_algorithm. This is the same algorithm used for MFA.

Here is the python implementation, you can find implementation in other languages as well.
https://pypi.org/project/pyotp/2.0.1/

Backend:

1. Create a random key and save it static database.
2. When client request for token create a token(+base64 conversion) using random key and send back to client.
3. When your server gets the token(-base64 conversion). Using the same random key verify the received token.
4. The totp algorithm will ensure that the old tokens are not valid.

You token is usually valid for 30 secs. so you may want decide on managing the validity of tokens.